# How to correctly persist Nvidia display configuration?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution, nvidia-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme laptop. It has a native display resolution of 3840x2160. But on the 15" laptop, that's tiny. Rather than dealing with application scaling (and the inevitable application that doesn't scale correctly), my preference is to simply run the display at 1920x1080 resolution.

Unfortunately, 1920x1080 is not an option in the Gnome Display Settings app (I'm using vanilla-gnome-desktop). The only option available is 3840x1080 (maybe something isn't detected correctly?).

**However**, I am able to run at 1920x1080 resolution using the nvidia-settings application after installing the proprietary Nvidia driver. Unfortunately, it seems that any changes I make in this app are lost on reboot. This seems to be a common "problem" - there are tons of questions about it all over the internet, with a pretty wide range of solutions.

**Currently**, my display runs at the default native resolution 3840x2160 when I log in. I've put the command `nvidia-settings --assign "CurrentMetaMode=DPY-3: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}"` into a `.desktop` file that I can run easily to reset the resolution. This **works**, but it's not a great experience to run this every time I log in or lock the screen.

**What is the proper way to persist this setting?**

Or, **How can I make other resolutions available to Gnome Display Settings** (which generally remembers its config in my experience)?

---

As [man nvidia-settings](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/alt-nvidia-current-updates-settings.1.html) suggests, I've tried making a `~/.xinitrc` that does `nvidia-settings --load-config-only &` before continuing to load `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, but this does not work for me since my `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` file does not seem to contain display resolution, even after saving my settings from the application. I've also tried using `nvidia-settings --assign` (as above) in my `~/.xinitrc`, but this doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: Move or copy  your desktop-file to ~/.config/autostart/ Maybe you must create the folder first.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. But that can't be the "official" way of doing this right? The best we can do is a script that runs _after_ I log in to re-adjust my display settings? I'm hoping for something that would make it load correctly initially rather than adjusting it after it's already started incorrectly. Also, I'm the only user on this computer, so I'm comfortable doing this at a system config level if necessary.

Comment: Also, what about when I lock my screen and the config is lost?

Answer (score 0):

I am on a machine here in 2021, with the same problem:  I have to re-set screen resolution on reboot and when I return from switching devices (HDMI Switch between computer and BluRay Player).  my "Metamodes" and Ubuntu diaply settings are all 1920x1080, but the resolution always reverts to Auto with 3840x2160--which is too high for a living room 40" screen used to stream video.  My 'work around' is to create a command-line alias

```
alias nv='nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60"'
```

Then I open a terminal and run 'nv' every time I reboot, or switch-back to the computer.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS  Video: NVIDIA GTX 1650 SUPER  Video Driver: nvidia-driver-460

Comment: I no longer have the problem from my original question. I don't recall exactly what fixed it, but I think it was an OS update. At some point, resolutions started showing up in Gnome display settings and I was able to set up what I want there, and they persist as I'd expect between reboots. I'm using nvidia drivers and I'm *not* using Wayland.